# $B^{3}=A\iff A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Examine if there is matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$B^3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & -1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm pretty sure that due to the fact that the $4\times 4$ matrix isn't diagonalizable, there can't be such a matrix $B$.

Is this correct? And if it is how do I prove that?

Comment: Could help me proving it without Jordan forms?

Comment: (I deleted my comment for some reason, so here it is again, with some additions) $B$ is nilpotent, because $B^{12} = (B^3)^4 = 0$. However, we have $B^6 = (B^3)^2$ is non-zero, so $B^4$ must be non-zero. This is a contradiction for a $4\times 4$ matrix. The most straight-forward way to show that is with Jordan forms. I'm thinking there must be a more elementary approach with ranks and kernels and images, I just can't see it right now.

Comment: VakiPitsi You could try and prove the following pieces: 1) Zero is the only eigenvalue of $B$. 2) The linear transformation gotten by restricting $B$ to its image doesn't have any other eigenvalues either. 3) Therefore the eigenspace belonging to  the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ of $B^2$ must be at least two dimensional. 4) The same about $B^3$. Contradicting the given form of $B^3$. This is really a low key version of JCForms, so may be a better idea is out there?

Comment: @Arthur Doesn't your reasoning over $B^{12}=0$ imply that $B$ is nilpotent and therefore $B$ is not diagonalizable over *any* field?

Comment: @Arthur Cayley-Hamilton also does the trick here

Comment: @Omnomnomnom could you explain how?

Comment: @VakiPitsi If a $4 \times 4$ matrix $B$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue, then its characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = (x-0)^4 = x^4$.  C-H tells us that we must therefore have $B^4 = 0$.

Comment: Ohh yes I see since p(B)=0. I think this is the best solution so far! Thanks a lot, very enlightening

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in your assumption, but you're incorrect in your argument.

An outline of a proof it with elementary techniques we can use Gauss elimination to show that there's a base where $B$ would be upper triangular, that is on the form $B=(D+U)$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is strictly upper. Now $B^3 = (D+U)^3 = D^3 + U^2D + UDU + DU^2 + UD^2 + DUD + D^2U + U^3$ which we can see it's diagonal is $D^3$ (follows from the fact that the product of a diagonal and strictly upper or two strictly upper is strictly upper).

This implies that $B$ is strictly upper and then in that base $B^3$ would have just one non-zero element at the upper right and there is no way such a matrix would have that representation in any base.

The fault with your attempt is that (for real matrices anyway) $B^3=A$ is not equivalent to $A$ being diagonalizable. $A$ not being diagonalizable does not even exclude the posibility that $A=B^3$ for some matrix $B$. Let for example $B$ be a suitable rotation which makes $A=B^3$ a nontrivial rotation too which is a nontrivial rotation in any base (and therefore not diagonal).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I got it